# Cannot open files in texlive directory

Tags: files, directory, chmod, chown, latex

I've installed texlive 2023 via `tlmgr`, the directory is `/usr/local/texlive/2023/` and update it with `sudo tlmgr --self --all --no-auto-remove update` as I've been doing it for years. It works perfectly fine except that I cannot open the documentations.

So changed the rights to access the files: `sudo chown -hR root:MyName /usr/local/textlive/2023/texmf-dist/doc/` and `sudo chmod -R g=u /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/doc/`

That doesn't change anything. Whenever I click in the folder a window appears

```
Anmeldung erforderlich

Anmeldung ist für die Ausführung des Dienstes

gvfsd-admin erforderlich

MyName

[ Passwort ]
```

Means something like "login required. For the execution of gvfsd-admin login is required" As soon as I enter my password another window pops up

```
Anmeldung erforderlich

Anmeldung ist für die Ausführung von Dateivorgängen erforderlich

My Name

[ Passwort ]
```

Meaning "login required. For the execution of something-with-files login is required." It still doesn't help. If I click on a file in this directory it says

```
Oops! Something went wrong. Don't have permission to access the requested location.

[ OK ]
```

If I click on whatever.pdf

```
»file:///tmp/evince-11838/document.HD7D41-whatever.pdf«

konnte nicht geöffnet werden.
```

"Document cannot be opened. ... not supported.

What can I do?